# Java object taking too much space in Tomcat session (Legacy code)

Tags: java, session, tomcat, memory, tomcat6

I am maintaining a legacy GUI application running on Tomcat6 and in some cases, when an user logs in, the application loads a massive java object into session and it takes a lot of memory (up to 200MB).
I installed psi-probe to monitor the memory and it shows this:

Current memory usage is 99.3%

Free: 3.41 MB Total: 487.25 MB Max: 487.25 MB

I would like to avoid touching the structure of the object itself because it is also a monster of complexity and I would probably break something.
I don't really know what options I have. I was thinking of trying to serialize it and write it as a file on the drive and access it there on demand.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: You need to defer the loading until it is actually required, and avoid storing it in the user session: see if you can make it request-scoped for example. You'll have to locate the places where it is stored in the session and the places where it is acquired from the session, and change them. And shoot the designer and previous implementors.

Comment: Yes I think I will try to go that way for now and try to load it when needed and remove it afterwards. It seems to be best. But the whole thing is very complex.

Comment: Well, after testing, it appears that the object needs 3.5s to be instanciated. This can't be done whenever the user clicks on a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to not load the large object into the session,
you will need to load a place holder into the session then use the place holder to get access to the object or the data in the object.

One technique is to create one or more rows in a database that contain the same data as is in the large object,
store a key to the row (or rows) in the session,
then use the key to access the data.
This will avoid using the large object.

Comment: The thing is that object has many many nested objects in it, it is a very complex structure.

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, it seems to me that the object is unimportant; the data contained in the objec is what you care about.

Comment: Yes the object is created at login and stores all the data the user could need from an xml file. The point is that the process to create this object from the xml file is very complex and many developers have worked on it, each adding more complexity to it.

My first idea was to try to load the precise data needed from the xml file, on demand, but it seems extremely difficult and could generate may side effects.

Comment: You have the data in the xml file.  consider loading it to a database then accessing it from there.

Comment: The xml file itself is not too complex, what the application does is that it reads it and constructs many very complex objects out of it and then put them all together in that huge object I have problems with. These objects can't be simply stored in the database. Unless you mean storing the serialized java objects.

Comment: In the end I think I will go with that solution, I think it is the cleanest way to do it. Cheers!